# Closure lifetime in Rust through simple pattern

Tags: struct, rust, closures, lifetime

I'm trying to recreate a simple callback pattern in Rust using 2 structs. One will pass a bit of logic to execute whenever the other one is ready. The issue here is that the logic will run only if a certain value from the struct is true.

I can understand why the reference to Foo needs to live for `'static` in this case, but I'm not sure how to refactor so that it compiles.

Seems like a pretty regular use case, but maybe I'm missing something since I'm new to Rust.

```
struct Foo {
    value: bool,
}

struct Bar {
    closure: Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo {
            value: false,
        }
    }
    fn set_closure(&self, b: &mut Bar) {
        b.closure = self.get_closure();
    }
    fn get_closure(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn() -> ()> {
        return Box::new(|| {
            if self.value {
                println!("true");
            } else {
                println!("false");
            }
        });
    }
}
impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Bar {
            closure: Box::new(|| {})
        }
    }
    
}
fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new();
    let mut bar = Bar::new();
    foo.set_closure(&mut bar);
    let closure = bar.closure;
    closure();
}
```

Playground link -> [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=638910142ebff3dd8469ff77b97b7ea3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `move` the value into the closure:

```rust
fn get_closure(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn() -> ()> {
    let value = self.value;
    Box::new(move || {
        if value {
            println!("true");
        } else {
            println!("false");
        }
    })
}
```

Notice that in your example value is a `bool` which is *Copy*. If not you can either capture a reference or clone it. (If capturing a reference you may need to adjust some lifetimes there).
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0341e3b83c2f54870f424d02b9a05543)